# selecting second element child java-script

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alight so i have 4 containers, when you click a button in a container a popup shows the image and heading of the container you clicked on i worked out how to do the image but i cant get the heading it is the second element child in the container. please note this is a school assignment and i can only use html css and java-script. please no hate im very new to this.
Here is my code please help

---

```
document.getElementById('bigImage').src = 
 this.parentNode.firstElementChild.src;

document.getElementById('title').textContent = 
this.parentNode.second ElementChild.textContent;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var element = document.getElementById('bigImage');
var parentElement = element.parentElement;
parentElement.children[0]; // <- first child
parentElement.children[1]; // <- second child
```

Comment: No problem. Please set my answer as the accepted. I'm hunting for reputation :)

Comment: Also, you should now there are several solutions. To learn more you can always open the Development Console (under View->Developer if you run Chrome) and grab an element of your page and play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's an assignment so no coding for you.

```
this.parentNode.second ElementChild
```

is incorrect. Please read and understand [NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) to see if it is relevent to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Code for Selecting and Manipulating the second Child in an unordered list.

```
document.firstElementChild.lastElementChild.children[1].children[1].innerHTML = "Name";
```

Note that you can change the array number to appropriately to get the correct child.